# Heroku Staging App Subdomain DNS Configuration

Tags: heroku, web, dns

I want to have 2 heroku apps use the same domain.

I recently set up a staging version of my Heroku application on a new app in Heroku. Everything is running fine, but I want the url of my staging app to be similar to my production application. For example my production site's URL is http://www.mysite.com and I want a staging url to be http://staging.mysite.com.

I setup a new CNAME record with a value staging. My DNS configuration is as follows:

```
Hostname    RecordType      Value
@           A               62.116.130.8
www         CNAME           myapp.herokuapp.com
staging     CNAME           staging-myapp.herokuapp.com
```

Does anyone have an experience trying this?
I'm too cheap to pay $7/month for DNS management through Zeringo or equivalent service. I'd rather just live with having the shitty staging-myapp.herokuapp.com url.

Comment: That should be fine. Are you encountering any problems getting this to work?

Comment: When I do this, I usually forget to add the new domain to the heroku config under apps > settings > domains. If you're getting a heroku error on the new subdomain, it'll be this.

Comment: I simply get Server Not Found. ping/host check says the domain doesn't resolve to any IP. I've also added the URL in the staging app's settings on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days I came back to this issue. With the settings above it is now working. I think it just took unusually long for the changes to propagate or maybe DNS flushing was not working.